# phonegap plugin doesn't compile [Pluggin attached]

Tags: cordova, plugins

My Plugin GitHub: https://github.com/keglevich3/Notificationplugin

When I try to compile my project I get the next error, I have no idea what can it be.
I don't know why the compiler can't find the calss, despite the face that it copy it to the android folder:

```
-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to G:\phonegao\phomegapme\platforms\android
\ant-build\classes
    [javac] G:\phonegao\phomegapme\platforms\android\src\com\vendrov\plugins\Not
ificationManager.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    [javac] com.vendrov.plugins.NotificationManager;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED`enter code here`
C:\Program Files\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\tools\ant\build.
xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\tools\ant\build.
xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 2 seconds
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,G:\phonegao\phomegap
me\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
   [error] cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
```